# Getting alternate rows to be different colors in a pdf

Tags: css, laravel

I've created a pdf and now I'm trying to style it. I've been sort of successfully on most of it, but I can't get my rows to be different colour. What I would like to happen is that with every odd row it needs to be a certain colour. I'm also having a problem with getting my font to work as well and I'm not understanding why.

I'm also using laravel and barryvdh/laravel-dompdf to create my pdf.

Here is my pdf

```
<html style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>{{ $order->invoice_number }}</title>

        <style>
            body{
                font-family: Arial;
            }

            .invoice_table .table {
                display: table;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .invoice_table .table .thead {
                display: table-header-group;
            }

            .invoice_table .table .tr {
                display: table-row;
            }

            .invoice_table .table .thead .tr .th {
                display: table-cell;
            }

            .invoice_table .table .thead .th {
                padding: 13px 0 12px;
            }

            .invoice_table .table .tbody {
                display: table-row-group;
            }

            /* CODE TO MAKE THE ROWS A DIFFERENT COLOUR */
            .invoice_table .table .tbody .tr:nth-child(odd){
                background-color: #4C8BF5;
                color: #fff;
            }

            .invoice_table .table .tr .td {
                display: table-cell;
            }

            .invoice_table .table .tbody .td {
                padding: 20px 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <div class="invoice_table" style="width: 700px; margin: 30px auto;">
            <div class="table" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
                <div class="thead" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
                    <div class="tr" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
                        <div class="th"></div>
                        <div class="th" style="border: 1px solid #000;">Description</div>
                        <div class="th" style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid #000;">Qty</div>
                        <div class="th" style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid #000;">Unit Price</div>
                        <div class="th" style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid #000;">Total Price</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tbody">
                    @foreach($order_item->items as $item)
                        <div class="tr">
                            <div class="td"></div>
                            <div class="td" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
                                {{ $item['item']['title'] }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="td" style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid #000;">
                                {{ $item['qty'] }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="td" style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid #000;">
                                R {{ $item['item']['price'] }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="td" style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid #000;">
                                R {{ $item['price'] }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach

                    <div class="tr">
                        <div class="td" rowspan="3" colspan="3" style="padding: 50px 0 5px 0; border: 1px solid #000;"></div>
                        <div class="td" style="text-align: right; padding: 50px 0 5px 0; border: 1px solid #000;">
                            SUBTOTAL:
                        </div>
                        <div class="td" style="text-align: center; padding: 50px 0 5px 0; border: 1px solid #000;">
                            R {{ $order_item->totalPrice }}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @if(!empty($order->delivery_fee))
                        <div class="tr">
                            <div class="td" style="text-align: right; padding: 0 0 5px 0; border: 1px solid #000;">
                                DELIVERY FEE:
                            </div>
                            <div class="td" style="text-align: center; padding: 0 0 5px 0; border: 1px solid #000;">
                                R {{ $order->delivery_fee }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <div class="tr">
                        <div class="td" style="text-align: right; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #000;">
                            TOTAL:
                        </div>
                        <div class="td" style="text-align: center; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #000;">
                            R {{ $order->order_price }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not pdf but HTML there must be something you are obviously missing to explain like what library you use to generate a PDF out of that HTML

Comment: I'm using laravel and I used the barryvdh/laravel-dompdf to create the pdf

Comment: Rather edit your question and put this info in than in a comment, this is a crucial information for people to help you. You also may want to add relevant tags like laravel to your question

Comment: Sure. I've updated my question

Comment: IMHO barryvdh/laravel-snappy it's better and faster at doing html to pdf conversion

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue but i solved this problem. Let's see

```
.table-bordered tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
```

I am using table instead of div. I suggest you to use table if possible. PDF does not support any class instead of **tr:nth-child**

Comment: Perfect, this worked for me! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below css to achiev.

```
.invoice_table .table .tbody tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
.invoice_table .table .tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```